# Select "case when"... yields grouped results... how to obtain aggregate data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Newer SQL user working with SQL Server 2014 SP2.

I'm trying to determine how to improve my results on a particular query.

The problem is that when I select data with a `Case When`, it requires me to use `group by` to aggregate the data.

I am trying to eliminate this `group by`, and have not been able to determine a viable method for this query.

Query yields these results:

```
StoreID Devices playing devices FullScreenPlays PIPPlays
--------------------------------------------------------
 1296      1           0               0           0
 1296      7           7               7           0
 1296      7           7               0           7
```

I am trying to achieve something more like this:

```
StoreID Devices playing devices FullScreenPlays PIPPlays
--------------------------------------------------------------
  1296     8           7               7            7
```

I've tried several variants of calling the `group by`, and I've tried several variants of the `case when`, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Any insight would be appreciated!

SQL code is here:

```
DECLARE @Location varchar(50) = '1296'

SELECT 
    Location.ExternalCode As [StoreID],
    COUNT(DISTINCT imdd.DeviceID) AS Devices,
    COUNT(DISTINCT esr.DeviceID) AS [playing devices],
    (CASE 
        WHEN (esr.EventID = 925) 
           THEN (COUNT(DISTINCT esr.DeviceID)) 
           ELSE 0 
     END) AS [FullScreenPlays],
    (CASE 
        WHEN (esr.EventID = 926) 
           THEN (COUNT(DISTINCT esr.DeviceID)) 
           ELSE 0 
     END) AS [PIPPlays]
 FROM 
     [iSenseMD].dbo.Location WITH (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN 
     iSenseMD.dbo.LocationAttribute la WITH (NOLOCK) ON Location.LocationID = la.LocationID
                                                     AND la.AttributeID = 7
                                                     AND la.Value = 1
LEFT JOIN 
    [iSenseMD].[dbo].Device imdd WITH (NOLOCK) ON location.LocationID = imdd.LocationID
                                               AND imdd.DeviceName NOT IN ('iX Gateway', 'A312778', 'A294874', '334873')
LEFT JOIN  
    [iSenseAnalytics].[dbo].[EventStringRollup] esr WITH (NOLOCK) ON imdd.LocationID = esr.LocationID 
                                                                  AND imdd.DeviceID = esr.DeviceID
                                                                  AND esr.IntervalID = 1
                                                                  AND esr.EventID IN (925, 926)  --all plays
                                                                  AND esr.RollupTimestamp >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0) 
                                                                  AND esr.RollupTimestamp < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
WHERE 
    Location.IsActive = 1
    AND Location.LocationName NOT LIKE '%duplicate%'
    AND Location.ExternalCode = @Location  --this to add the declaration above as site constraint
GROUP BY 
    Location.ExternalCode, esr.EventID
ORDER BY 
    iSenseMD.dbo.Location.ExternalCode
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would put the query in a CTE and then aggregate it from there

```
WITH CTE_Example
AS
(    use iSenseMD
go

DECLARE @Location varchar(50) = '1296'

SELECT Location.ExternalCode As [StoreID]
,count(distinct imdd.DeviceID) as Devices
,count(distinct esr.DeviceID) as [playing devices]
,(case when (esr.EventID = 925) Then (count (distinct esr.DeviceID)) Else 0 End) As [FullScreenPlays]
,(case when (esr.EventID = 926) Then (count (distinct esr.DeviceID)) Else 0 End) As [PIPPlays]


FROM [iSenseMD].dbo.Location WITH (NOLOCK)

INNER JOIN iSenseMD.dbo.LocationAttribute la WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON Location.LocationID = la.LocationID
    AND la.AttributeID = 7
    AND la.Value = 1

left JOIN [iSenseMD].[dbo].Device imdd WITH (NOLOCK) ON location.LocationID = imdd.LocationID
    AND imdd.DeviceName NOT IN ('iX Gateway','A312778','A294874','334873')

left JOIN  [iSenseAnalytics].[dbo].[EventStringRollup] esr WITH (NOLOCK) ON imdd.LocationID = esr.LocationID and imdd.DeviceID = esr.DeviceID
    AND esr.IntervalID = 1
    AND esr.EventID IN (925, 926)  --all plays
    AND esr.RollupTimestamp >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) 
    AND esr.RollupTimestamp < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)



WHERE Location.IsActive = 1
    AND Location.LocationName NOT LIKE '%duplicate%'
    AND Location.ExternalCode = @Location  --this to add the declaration above as site constraint

GROUP BY Location.ExternalCode
    ,esr.EventID)

--A GROUP BY might not be allowed either, I can't remember. But I think it'll be fine, let me know if there are any issues

/* ORDER BY 
    iSenseMD.dbo.Location.ExternalCode */
--I don't think an ORDER BY is allowed in a CTE so I have it commented out for now. Is it an absolute within the query?

SELECT StoreID, SUM(Devices), SUM([playing devices]), SUM(FullScreenPlays), 
SUM(PIPPlays)
FROM CTE_Example
GROUP BY StoreID
```

Hope this helps and please let me know if there are any errors!

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your `case` statement inside your `count` aggregate. This way you can remove the `EventID` in the `group by`

**Example:**

```
COUNT(DISTINCT 
       CASE WHEN (esr.EventID = 925) THEN esr.DeviceID
       ELSE NULL
    END) AS [FullScreenPlays]
```

**Original:**

```
(CASE 
    WHEN (esr.EventID = 925) 
    THEN (COUNT(DISTINCT esr.DeviceID)) 
    ELSE 0 
 END) AS [FullScreenPlays]
```